# simple program not executing in c

Tags: c, runtime, syntax-error

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i, int a[5]={1,2,48,3,88};
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if (a[i]<a[i+1])
        {
            printf("%d",a[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("can't print");
        }
    }
}
```

The program is not executing at all. My aim was to print the number if the current number is less than the next number. It should print or else it will print can't print.

Comment: So what's the problem? Compiler error? Run-time error? Garbage output?

Comment: The program is not compiling at all. And the compiler will tell you what line the error is on.

Comment: This (badly indented) code doesn't compile, yet alone execute. Take another look at the compiler output.

Comment: I even have the impression that the original poster don't understand that C code needs to be compiled :-(

Answer (score 4):

In current versions of C you should specify a return type for `main` and the return type must be `int`. I also recommend specifying the parameter list.

```
int main(void)
```

If you want separate declarations for `i` and `a` (which I recommend) then you need to use a semi-colon to separate them, if you want one declaration (which I wouldn't recommend) you need to omit the second `int`.

```
int i; int a[5]={1,2,48,3,88};
```

or

```
int i, a[5]={1,2,48,3,88};
```

Your `printf` strings should end with a `\n` to ensure they are output where expected:

```
printf("%d\n",a[i]);
```

---

```
printf("can't print\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, for ur suggestion, the mistake was in the parameter list. Can you please explain a little about it.

Comment: @Joker666: The mistake shouldn't have been in the parameter list because `int main()` is perfectly valid, just not what I'd recommend.

Comment: I asked a friend and found out that it's because of the compiler. other than that my program was completely valid. thanks for ur help.

Comment: @Joker666: If it's because of the compiler, it's because the compiler is following the language. The lack of a return type for `main` and the declaration error are both invalid in the current version of C.

Comment: yeah, thats what he told me. thanks for ur time.

Answer (score 0):

Put a terminating newline `\n` in every printf, e.g. `printf("can't print\n");` or call `fflush(NULL)`.

Your declarations should be separated as

```
int i;
int a[5]={1,2,48,3,88};
```

Please indent your C code appropriately (on Linux, the `indent` utility can help).

Don't forget to compile your program with warnings and debugging information (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g myprog.c -o myprog` on Linux)

Comment: And how this `\n` helps for the current issue?